# How can i change slide indicators of a carousel as the viewport gets smaller?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a carousel similar to this one:

http://demo.sequencejs.com/pop-slide/

i want to change it so that as the screen gets smaller, the links on the bottom disappear and instead there would be dot indicators to change the slides

Comment: It would be good if you can post some code on what you have tried. That way it will be easy for someone to help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Use media queries to change those links at a certain page width.

Answer (score 0):

This is really hard to answer without code examples from your side but I will try:

Basically, you can add both indicators and just hide / show the elements with a css media query. This would be the cleanest and most performance friendly solution in my opinion.

If the slider plugin allows it, you could also detect the window width on rezize (be careful with this, it can hurt performance!) and unbind and rebind the slider with different options.